# Radio button not checking inside <a> tag

Tags: html, css, radio-button, anchor

When the text is clicked, the radio button is checked and when the little green patch is clicked the frame is working, why are they both not working at the same time? Can someone help me with this?

```css
body {
  user-select: none;
}

a {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #000;
  background: violet;
}

label {
  background: yellowgreen;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

input[type="radio"]:checked+a>label {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<input type="radio" name="list" id="1" />
<a href="Text1.html" target="frame">
  <label for="1">text</label>
</a>
<input type="radio" name="list" id="2" />
<a href="Text2.html" target="frame">
  <label for="2">text</label>
</a>
<input type="radio" name="list" id="3" />
<a href="Text3.html" target="frame">
  <label for="3">text</label>
</a>
<iframe name="frame"></iframe>
```

Comment: Why not `<label for="1">
  <input type="radio" name="list" id="1" />
  <a href="Text1.html" target="frame">text</a>
</label>`

Comment: Still similar problems @mplungjan

Answer (score 0):

Use this Type of Code:

```
<a href="Text1.html" target="frame">
  <input type="radio" name="list" id="1"/>
  <label for="1">text</label>
</a>
<iframe name="frame"></iframe>
```

Comment: Same problem not working @Priya Maheshwari

Comment: Now you can check this link. Maybe this helpfull for you 
[Link ]( https://codepen.io/Priyamaheshwari/pen/vYmwRZK )

Comment: The anchor tag is not redirecting to the specified frame!

Comment: Now you can check anchor tag is redirecting to the specified frame.

Answer (score 0):

Perhaps some JS?

You can even remove the radios here

```js
const labels = [...document.querySelectorAll("#nav label")];
const iFrame = document.querySelector("iframe");
document.getElementById("nav").addEventListener("click", function(e) {
  const label = e.target.closest("label");
  if (label) {
    labels.forEach(label => label.classList.remove("checked"));
    label.classList.add("checked");
    iFrame.location = `text${label.id}.html`
  }
})
```

```css
body {
  user-select: none;
}

label {
  text-decoration: none;
  margin: 10px;
  color: #000;
  background: yellowgreen;
}

span {
  background: violet;
}

input[type="radio"] {
  display: none;
}

.checked {
  color: red;
}
```

```html
<div id="nav">
  <label id="1" />text<span>&nbsp;</span></label>
  <label id="2" />text<span>&nbsp;</span></label>
  <label id="3" />text<span>&nbsp;</span></label>
</div>
<iframe name="frame"></iframe>
```